# Using Structs inside of classes from other classes

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, struct

I have recently converted a VB class to C# and it seems I ran into a problem; I think I know how to solve it but with all my reading I am now looking for a more clear answer with guidance.
Consider the following code with a struct FileDetail inside (This is just an example - so please do not assume it is FileDetail as in Files..)
The Struct needs to be accessed internally and externally - they are passed by value and not reference types so struct appears to be the way to go here instead of a class (looking at the whole code that is).  In the form class MyForm I get the error that FileDetails does not exist in class IAFT.

```
public class IAFT
{
    public struct FileDetail
    {
        public string FileType;
        public int FileNumber;
    }
}

public class MyForm
{
   MyForm()
   {
       public IAFT.FileDetail fd = new IAFT.FileDetail();
       // IAFT.FileDetail
   }
}
```

ERROR I get.
The type name '*FileDetail*' does not exist in the type 'IAFT' (CS0426)
Red squigly in VS2013 is under the type declaration; left hand side of the assignment.

Both are in the same namespace if that is any help.

I have read posts on SO that tell me I can declare my variable fd just as it is above (did not make sense to me since I have no instance - but I tried it.) I do not want to create an instance to get an instance ; I believe I want the one as it exists inside the instance of IAFT. Maybe there is something I am not understanding.

Should I encapsulate the struct as a class instead?
Should I put the struct outside of the class IAFT? 
[This is what I was thinking I should do.]

Should I do something else ?

Comment: IAFT needs to be static for you to access it without actually creating an instance of one.

Comment: If you need to access it from other classes, it shouldn't be encapsulated inside another class. Pull it out on its own.

Comment: if you make your `MyForm` ctor public, and remove the `public` keyword inside the ctor, this actually compiles and runs, as inadvisable as it is.

Comment: Your code does not compile.  You are declaring a member inside a constructor.  Please post the _actual_ code (or at least something that compiles).  There should be no problem accessing a public nested class from another class.

Comment: @DStanley Well, the premise of the question is that the code doesn't compile.  The issue is that the compiler error message he claims he gets is different than what the code shown would produce.

Comment: As the OP said "this is just an example"

Comment: @Allan S. Hansen what kind of other ramifications might this have on the code considering in VB it was encapsulated ? As instances of the class IAFT would have the struct internal (it is a by value object) would there be anything I might be on the look out for ? 
BTW thanks to all those who are reading the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example is wrong and wont compile. Your error is that you are delcaring

```
 public IAFT.FileDetail fd = new IAFT.FileDetail();
```

Inside the public constructor. You cannot declare scope in a function scoped variable. If you take the Public declaration off your code compiles just fine.

So try this;

```
public class IAFT
{
    public struct FileDetail
    {
        public string FileType;
        public int FileNumber;
    }
}

public class MyForm
{

    public MyForm()
    {
        IAFT.FileDetail fd = new IAFT.FileDetail();
    }
}
```

Its perfectly good practise to nest classes.

Comment: `Its perfectly good practice to nest classes.`  Well, it *works* in this case.  That doesn't mean it's a good idea to do this in this way.

Comment: Whats your justification for infering bad practise here ? Its fully supported by the language and can make code tidier - its just another way of namespacing. It has the advantage that outside the class you have to refer to it by its full name, because you cannot use "using". Its uncommon but valid.

Comment: @Servy If the nesting has any sense (it holds data exposed only by that class, it's used to call only their functions, etc, etc) I don't see any problem. Why it is not a good idea to do this? (curious)

Comment: @Gusman It would depend on context, but given the usage it sure doesn't seem like it's strongly tied to the containing class, to the degree that it ought to be nested in it.

Comment: @Servy well, I tend to ignore the context on the examples as they're that, just examples, but maybe in this case you're right as it seems a piece of cropped code from a program.

Comment: @PhillipH I upped this because your answer is actually telling me there is something wrong with how the converter converted and also what the proper way to do this is; while many comments suggest this to be bad practice and also reading seems people feel it to be bad. I do not know what the ramifications of putting it outside the class are. Also since I am taking parts of code and using only portions in this conversion - I can't be sure if I will need this outside of the object; however if I do I will need the object as well so it seems fitting.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do the struct static nor moving it outside, the problem lies that you declared the var as public inside a function, and that's not allowed, localvariables don't have access modifiers as they're local.

Try this:

```
public class IAFT
{
    public struct FileDetail
    {
        public string FileType;
        public int FileNumber;
    }
}

public class MyForm
{
   public IAFT.FileDetail fd = new IAFT.FileDetail();
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I would to it this way:

```
public class IAFT
{
    fileDetail FileDetail = new fileDetail();
}

public class fileDetail
{
    public string FileType;
    public int FileNumber;
}

public class MyForm
{
   MyForm()
   {
       IAFT.FileDetail.FileType = "test";
       //IAFT.FileDetail
   }
}
```

I hope that it works, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Well, it wont work. IAFT has not been initialized and FileDetail property is not a static so... wont compile.